# State not saving in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a code where the moment I open a page I am setting a List Array this way:

```
const [myArray, updateArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

        var myItem= [...array1];

        if (state.pageNumber == 1 myItem= [...array2];
        else if (state.pageNumber == 2) myItem= [...array3]; 


        updateArray(myItem);

    }, []);
```

This works fine and the page is portraying the right array. The problem comes when I have to click a button and call the data on the updated array again. I have a function that when on click I have to read the array I updated. The problem is that "myArray" is coming up as blank. It only shows the data if the state changes for some reason like when I save my code again.

```
    const handleSelect = (selectedIndex) => {
        console.log(myArray);
    };
```

Above comes blank even after it correctly updated and displays correctly on the page.

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: `else if (state.pageNumber == 1) myItem= [...array3]` will never be called because the if has same condition.

Comment: Thanks, code updated. This is just a demo code but the problem is that myArray comes up empty.

Comment: Why are you using `var` in JSX code? Use `let` instead.

Comment: Where does `state.pageNumber` come from?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt help. I have also noticed that if in UseEffect I update a text, and I try to call it in the function it comes up empty also. Do variables not get saved in UseEffect? Even if I erase the state.pageNumber and leave the default update. It still doesnt get saved

Comment: Please make sure your [mre] covers the problem, at the moment it might be a bit too _minimal_ and not quite _reproducible_ enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the previous state and return it for the next state just by adding a callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
     updateArray((array)=> [...(pageNumber === 1 ? array1 : pageNumber === 2 ? array2 : array)]);
}, [pageNumber]);
```

If you want to set a new array everytime `pageNumber` changes, you should set the `pageNumber` as the `useEffect` dependency.

If you want to update the array everytime `array1` and `array2` changes, you should also add it to the `useEffect` dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
   //code
}, [pageNumber, array1, array2]);
```

Note: You should create a new copy of object or array every time you set a new state to re-render it.

Comment: I think you may have a point about the `useEffect` dependencies, but I'm not sure your suggestion to use a setState updater function is better, and the OP is making a copy of state for their update. These two things add a lot of noise to your answer and make it less-likey that readers will find the good part/s of it.

Comment: Nested ternaries are almost never a good option. They're awful to try to read/understand

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of pagination in React using Redux Toolkit. Your component should know how to access the items from the Redux store, along with the current page size and page index.

```js
// Visible books
const pagedBooks = useMemo(() => books.slice(startIndex, endIndex), [
  books,
  endIndex,
  startIndex
]);
```

I exported the start index, end index, and page count calculation functions as well, since they will be needed outside of the pagination component.

Full demo here: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-18-pagination-example-x37l25)

### Package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "8.0.5",
  }
}
```

### Paginator.jsx

```
import { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faAngleDoubleLeft,
  faAngleDoubleRight,
  faAngleLeft,
  faAngleRight
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const calcStartIndex = (pageSize, pageIndex) => pageSize * pageIndex;

const calcEndIndex = (items, pageSize, startIndex) =>
  Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, items.length);

const calcPageCount = (items, pageSize) =>
  Math.floor(items.length / pageSize) + Math.sign(items.length % pageSize);

const Paginator = ({
  changeIndex,
  changePageSize,
  items,
  pageIndex,
  pageSize
}) => {
  const pageCount = useMemo(() => calcPageCount(items, pageSize), [
    items,
    pageSize
  ]);

  const startIndex = useMemo(() => calcStartIndex(pageSize, pageIndex), [
    pageSize,
    pageIndex
  ]);

  const endIndex = useMemo(() => calcEndIndex(items, pageSize, startIndex), [
    items,
    pageSize,
    startIndex
  ]);

  const onPageSizeChange = useCallback((e) => changePageSize(+e.target.value), [
    changePageSize
  ]);

  const onFirstClick = useCallback(() => {
    changeIndex(0);
  }, [changeIndex]);

  const onPrevClick = useCallback(() => {
    changeIndex(pageIndex - 1);
  }, [changeIndex, pageIndex]);

  const onNextClick = useCallback(() => {
    changeIndex(pageIndex + 1);
  }, [changeIndex, pageIndex]);

  const onLastClick = useCallback(() => {
    changeIndex(pageCount - 1);
  }, [changeIndex, pageCount]);

  return (
    <div className="Paginator">
      <div className="pagination-col">
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={onPageSizeChange}
          title="Items per page"
        >
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="pagination-col pagination-actions">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="pagination-btn"
          disabled={pageIndex <= 0}
          onClick={onFirstClick}
          title="Go to first page"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDoubleLeft} />
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="pagination-btn"
          disabled={pageIndex <= 0}
          onClick={onPrevClick}
          title="Go to previous page"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
        </button>
        <div>
          Page {pageIndex + 1} of {pageCount}
        </div>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="pagination-btn"
          disabled={pageIndex >= pageCount - 1}
          onClick={onNextClick}
          title="Go to next page"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="pagination-btn"
          disabled={pageIndex >= pageCount - 1}
          onClick={onLastClick}
          title="Go to last page"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDoubleRight} />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="pagination-col">
        {startIndex + 1}–{endIndex} of {items.length}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Paginator;

export { calcEndIndex, calcPageCount, calcStartIndex };
```

### Usage

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import BookItem from "./BookItem";
import Paginator, {
  calcEndIndex,
  calcPageCount,
  calcStartIndex
} from "./Paginator";

const LibraryView = () => {
  const { books } = useSelector((state) => state.library);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(5);

  useEffect(() => {
    const lastIndex = calcPageCount(books, pageSize) - 1;
    if (pageIndex > lastIndex) {
      setPageIndex(lastIndex);
    }
  }, [books, pageIndex, pageSize]);

  const startIndex = useMemo(() => calcStartIndex(pageSize, pageIndex), [
    pageSize,
    pageIndex
  ]);

  const endIndex = useMemo(() => calcEndIndex(books, pageSize, startIndex), [
    books,
    pageSize,
    startIndex
  ]);

  const pagedBooks = useMemo(() => books.slice(startIndex, endIndex), [
    books,
    endIndex,
    startIndex
  ]);

  const changeIndex = useCallback((newIndex) => setPageIndex(newIndex), []);

  const changePageSize = useCallback((newPageSize) => {
    setPageSize(newPageSize);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="LibraryView">
      <div className="Books">
        {pagedBooks.map((book) => (
          <BookItem key={book.isbn} {...book} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Paginator
        changeIndex={changeIndex}
        changePageSize={changePageSize}
        items={books}
        pageIndex={pageIndex}
        pageSize={pageSize}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LibraryView;
```